# Write pojo class for this xml file

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, xml-parsing

I'm getting null value when unmarshelling the xml file to java class. But the xml file as values corresponding to the its attributes. Is there any mistake in my pojo class or unmarshelling?
Please help

This is my pojo

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "")
@XmlRootElement(name = "CardUpdateResponse",namespace="http://www.samople.com/Prepaid")
public class FVCardUpdateResponse {

    @XmlElement(name = "AccountNumber")
    private String AccountNumber;

    @XmlElement(name = "ResCode")
    private String ResCode;

    @XmlElement(name = "ResErrorCode")
    private String ResErrorCode;

    @XmlElement(name = "ResErrorMsg")
    private String ResErrorMsg;

    //Setters and Getters
}
```

This is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CardUpdateResponse xmlns="http://www.samople.com/Prepaid">
    <CARDUPDATE_RET>
        <ResErrorMsg>ID Issue Date must be equal or less than present date</ResErrorMsg>
        <ResErrorCode>ErrIsud01</ResErrorCode>
        <ResCode>0</ResCode>
        <ACCOUNTNUMBER>2000000003918246</ACCOUNTNUMBER>
    </CARDUPDATE_RET>
</CardUpdateResponse>
```

this is code for unmarshelling

```
public class XmlUnmarshelling {

    public void unmarshell()
    {

        try
        {
            System.out.println("xml unmarshelling class");
            File file = new File("D:/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/tmpFiles/1.xml");

            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(FVCardUpdateResponse.class);

            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            FVCardUpdateResponse CARDUPDATE_ret = (FVCardUpdateResponse) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
            System.out.println("xml unmarshelled = "+CARDUPDATE_ret.getResErrorMsg());//Getting null value as response.
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your POJO doesn't have the same structure as your XML. `CardUpdateResponse` doesn't directly contain the properties in your POJO, it contains `CARDUPDATE_RET` element which contains the properties.

You could modify your POJO like this to match the XML:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "CardUpdateResponse", namespace="http://www.samople.com/Prepaid")
public static class CardUpdateResponseWrapper {

    @XmlElement(name="CARDUPDATE_RET")
    private FVCardUpdateResponse response;

    // Getter and setter for response

    public static class FVCardUpdateResponse {

        @XmlElement(name = "AccountNumber")
        private String AccountNumber;

        @XmlElement(name = "ResCode")
        private String ResCode;

        @XmlElement(name = "ResErrorCode")
        private String ResErrorCode;

        @XmlElement(name = "ResErrorMsg")
        private String ResErrorMsg;

        // Getters and setters
    }

}
```

Now the `CardUpdateResponseWrapper` class will represent your root XML element and it will have instance of `FVCardUpdateResponse` which will represent the `CARDUPDATE_RET` XML element.

Do unmarshall it, just call:

```
File file = new File("D:/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/tmpFiles/1.xml");
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(CardUpdateResponseWrapper.class);
Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
CardUpdateResponseWrapper wrapper = (CardUpdateResponseWrapper) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);

 System.out.println(wrapper.getResponse().getResErrorMsg());
```

Comment: Thank you guys. I combined both the answers and got the exact output what i want. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the issue is a combination of two problems, one what Bohuslav is saying, the other you need to repeat your namespace on every XmlElement annotation, e.g.

```
 @XmlElement(name = "ResCode", namespace="http://www.samople.com/Prepaid")
```

and one particular issue, you need to match the cases as well so the name for AccountNumber should be capitalized `ACCOUNTNUMBER`

Comment: Thank you guys. I combined both the answers and got the exact output what i want. Thank you so much.